# How to transpose MySQL rows and repeat column headers?

Tags: mysql, transpose

I have a mysql table that looks like:

```
id  group_id   item_code  item_label  item_detail    item_score
1   10         BLU123     Blue 123    Blah blah 123  3
2   10         BLU124     Blue 124    Blah blah 124  6
3   10         BLU125     Blue 125    Blah blah 125  2
```

Is there any sql statement that will output the table as:

```
group_id   item_code1  item_label1  item_detail1    item_score1  item_code2  item_label2  item_detail2    item_score2  item_code3  item_label3  item_detail3    item_score3
10         BLU123      Blue 123     Blah blah 123   3            BLU124      Blue 124     Blah blah 124   6            BLU125      Blue 125     Blah blah 125   2
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do that? In any case you will probably need to write code in your app instead of a SQL query to accomplish it.

Comment: Fascinating that you can downgrade because *you* don't know my reasoning.  Was wondering if this could be done so Excel component could be populated in 1 step.

Comment: Perhaps "repeat column headings" is misleading.  It would be fine for column headings to be `id group_id item_code1 item_label1 item_detail1 item_score1 item_code2 item_label2 item_detail2 item_score2`

Comment: Yes,essentially.  If, for example, I were in Excel I would cut row 2's values from columns C,D,E,F & paste into row 1's columns G,H,I,J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this if those really are the `id` values:

```
select group_id,
  max(case when id = 1 then item_code end) item_code1,
  max(case when id = 1 then item_label end) item_label1,
  max(case when id = 1 then item_detail end) iitem_detail1,
  max(case when id = 1 then item_score end) item_score1,
  max(case when id = 2 then item_code end) item_code2,
  max(case when id = 2 then item_label end) item_label2,
  max(case when id = 2 then item_detail end) iitem_detail2,
  max(case when id = 2 then item_score end) item_score2,
  max(case when id = 3 then item_code end) item_code3,
  max(case when id = 3 then item_label end) item_label3,
  max(case when id = 3 then item_detail end) iitem_detail3,
  max(case when id = 3 then item_score end) item_score3
from yourtable
group by group_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24dd2b/3)

Result:

```
| GROUP_ID | ITEM_CODE1 | ITEM_LABEL1 | IITEM_DETAIL1 | ITEM_SCORE1 | ITEM_CODE2 | ITEM_LABEL2 | IITEM_DETAIL2 | ITEM_SCORE2 | ITEM_CODE3 | ITEM_LABEL3 | IITEM_DETAIL3 | ITEM_SCORE3 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       10 |     BLU123 |    Blue 123 | Blah blah 123 |           3 |     BLU124 |    Blue 124 | Blah blah 124 |           6 |     BLU125 |    Blue 125 | Blah blah 125 |           2 |
```

If you cannot rely on the `id` in the table, then you could add a row number to the records you are returning:

```
select group_id,
  max(case when rownum = 1 then item_code end) item_code1,
  max(case when rownum = 1 then item_label end) item_label1,
  max(case when rownum = 1 then item_detail end) iitem_detail1,
  max(case when rownum = 1 then item_score end) item_score1,
  max(case when rownum = 2 then item_code end) item_code2,
  max(case when rownum = 2 then item_label end) item_label2,
  max(case when rownum = 2 then item_detail end) iitem_detail2,
  max(case when rownum = 2 then item_score end) item_score2,
  max(case when rownum = 3 then item_code end) item_code3,
  max(case when rownum = 3 then item_label end) item_label3,
  max(case when rownum = 3 then item_detail end) iitem_detail3,
  max(case when rownum = 3 then item_score end) item_score3
from 
(
  select group_id, item_code, item_detail,
    item_label, item_score,
    @rn:=@rn+1 rownum
  from yourtable, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
  where group_id = 10
  order by id
) src
group by group_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b01e9/5)

Answer (score 3):

For what you want, to select all rows to insert into one row in Excel. Have as many rows in your table as you like.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        group_id,',', GROUP_CONCAT( 
            CONCAT_WS(',', item_code, item_label, item_detail, item_score) 
        )
    )
FROM thetable
```

Returns CSV:

```
10,BLU123,Blue 123,Blah blah 123,3,BLU124,Blue 124,Blah blah 124,6,BLU125,Blue 125,Blah blah 125,2
```

Comment: Was just trying this exact solution (except nested CONCAT inside GROUP_CONCAT).  It would work if my data weren't so long.  After a few rows the CSV just cuts off.  I would +1 but I'm too new here.  Thanks for the reply!